# JavaScript pluck and process values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a JavaScript array containing objects with few attributes. I want to create a new array from this array containing the value of "name" attribute of the objects. Also, I want to process the "name" by using jQuery's _.escape method.

I can see that "pluck" of underscore can be quite handy in getting an array of "name" attribute values. However I could not find if there is any way to process the value while plucking so that I do not need to iterate over the array and call _.escape on each.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options for you:

#### `reduce`

One fairly traditional approach to this is to use `reduce` — either [Underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce), or ES5's built-in one:

```
// ES5
var newArray = existingArray.reduce([], function(result, current) {
    if (condition) {
        result.push(current.relevantProperty);
    }
    return result;
});

// Underscore:
var newArray = _.reduce(existingArray, function(result, current) {
    if (condition) {
        result.push(current.relevantProperty);
    }
    return result;
}, []);
```

(There I've used the name `result` for the argument typically called `memo` or `last`, because we don't actually change its value, just its contents.)

#### `$.map`

Since you've tagged your question `jquery`, another option is `$.map`. Unlike either Underscore's or ES5's `map`, `$.map` lets you leave entries out of the resulting array by returning `null` or `undefined`. So:

```
var newArray = $.map(existingArray, function(entry) {
    return condition ? entry.relevantProperty : null;
});
```

#### `for` / `forEach` / `each`

Or of course, there's nothing wrong with a good old-fashioned `for` loop, `forEach` call, or `_.each` call. The latter:

```
var newArray = [];
_.each(existingArray, function(entry) {
    if (condition) {
        newArray.push(entry.relevantProperty);
    }
});
```

The only downside to this is it can't be one expression, so the first two are sometimes more appropriate if you're passing into a function or something (although using a temp variable isn't the end of the world, and can help debugging).